# Dagger singleton vs Kotlin object

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

To define a singleton, should I use Kotlin object declaration or to make an ordinary Kotlin class and inject it using dagger? In my opinion the first option is definitely easier but there may be a reason to use dagger in this situation that I'm not aware of.

**Option 1 (notice `object` keyword):**

```kotlin
object SomeUtil {
    // object state (properties)

    fun someFunction(number: Long) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Option 2 (notice `class` keyword):**

```kotlin
class SomeUtil {
    // object state (properties)

    fun someFunction(number: Long) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideTheUtil() = SomeUtil()
}
```

```kotlin
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    @Inject internal lateinit var util: SomeUtil
}
```

> **UPDATE 2019-07-03**

@Blackbelt said in comments that we should prefer option 2 for testability. But libraries like **MockK** can [mock `object`s](https://mockk.io#object-mocks) too. So do you still think option 2 is the preferred one?

Comment: `this situation that I'm not aware of`, testability ?

Comment: The only real reason you'd create this wrapper "util" class would be for testing, otherwise its pointless abstraction.

Comment: @MarkKeen I updated the question to generalize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to reconsider the need of `NumberFormatUtil` being a singleton. It might be cheaper if you use `@Reusable` with *Dagger* or even a factory without any scope directly.

If `NumberFormatUtil` is fairly simple and only provides a few utility methods, no state and no need for mocking in tests, you could use an `object` implementation, maybe using `@JvmStatic` for *Java*-inter-operability. But then you could go for global utility (extension) functions as well:

```
package xyz

fun formatNumber(number: Long) {
    // ...
}

fun Long.format() = formatNumber(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use option 2.

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a software design
>   pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one "single"
>   instance. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to
>   coordinate actions across the system.

From: [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

So, a singleton is single instance in a scope. In case of Android, it is virtual machine instance running the app. In case you need custom scopes, you have to use option 2 only.

But, if you have only static methods inside the object you want to inject its better to keep them as global methods and even get rid of `object`. No need to inject anything. It is similar to a java class with only static methods (I mentioned this point as it is a usual way of creating Utility classes).

However, if the `object` also has some state. I would recommend going dagger way. The `object` way does not provide with dependency injection. It only creates a Singleton. Your purpose for using dagger is dependency injection.