# Android Kotlin object vs Dagger2 for singleton models

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276849/dagger-singleton-vs-kotlin-object) question, but it was from the point of testability.
In my case, I see Dagger as an additional complexity for code (create @Provides methods, inject methods, remember all the right annotations). Should I still use Dagger if I just want to inject singletons like SharedPrefUtils? Is it really faster for this case?

Comment: if you _absolutely had to_ use dagger, it would have been part of the framework and mandatory. this means that it's optional. how you use it is up to you, whether it will be better or not is up to you to decide. we can't make those decisions for you as it will be entirely based on opinion/scenario

Comment: @a_local_nobody I understand that, I ask from a point of best practice as I am new to Kotlin after few years of Java.

Comment: again, best practice is up to you to decide.

Comment: frameworks like `koin` also exist for dependency injection, why not rather use koin over dagger ? or why use dagger over koin ? why even use either one? it depends on the scenario entirely

Comment: @a_local_nobody then the question morphs into "how to decide which one to use"

Comment: You've got bigger problems than Dagger if you have singleton Presenters.

Comment: `then the question morphs into "how to decide which one to use"` which is, again, up to you.

Comment: if there was only a single best way of doing something, we would never have different options or possible implementations available to begin with.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank you for your note, I used to use presenter to hold view state for whole lifecycle (there could be only one view instance at a time). Then I've researched a lil bit and they're not singleton anymore.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I understand, but "how to decide" asks for pros and cons or example cases.

Answer (score 2):

Dagger was not made for creating Singletons and if creating a singleton is the reason you want to add Dagger to your project, then its an overkill. Dagger is a dependency injection framework that helps make the process of providing and injecting dependencies easier in a complex project. The `@Singleton` would help you ensure that only a single instance of a class is created when satisfying your dependencies it is not an alternative to the Kotlin object, they could even be used together. So like other answers and comments suggest if you have a small project and you could use simple design patterns like [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), and [Abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Answer (score -1):

Dagger is a dependency injection framework. For very simple applications, you can go with manual injection which will save you time because dagger can be difficult to set up and work with from the beginning. However, if you are planning on a production application which has a very long life span and will contain multiple UIs and multiple classes,  then you are definitely going to need a dependency injection framework or strategy along the line.

There is an alternative for Kotlin which is Koin. Koin works more like a Service Locator and is easier to set up than Dagger but I will prefer dagger because it has survived the test of time.

It is up to you whether you want to use automatic dependency injection or manual injection so in the end you weigh your options and see what best fits your use case.

Comment: `For very simple applications, you can go with manual injection which will save you time because dagger can be difficult to set up and work with from the beginning` source for this ?

Comment: `However, if you are planning on a production application which has a very long life span and will contain multiple UIs and multiple classes, then you are definitely going to need a dependency injection framework or strategy along the line.` source for this ?